# EDIMAX RTL driver says: "This driver is activated but not currently in use"

Tags: drivers

I am trying to update a driver for EDIMAX usb wifi device, 
and after the unzip/install complete I go to the Additional Drivers 
dialog and see the line: "Realtek Wireless Lan Driver" 
but on the bottom of the screen I see the line says : 
"This driver is activated but not currently in use"

What can I do to make the system use it ?

Thanks in advance
Roman.

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard that that means the module is loaded into the kernel, but no device is currently using it. Try replugging the USB device?